# WooCommerce REST API Product variation 404

Tags: python, rest, api, woocommerce

**Set-up**

I run a WooCommerce webshop with several products, of which some have product variations.

I use the [WooCommerce REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) to adjust stuff in my webshop.

---

**My Code**

Calling a product with variations,

`product = uk_wcapi.get('products/51369').json()`

this works fine.

This product has several variations,

```
print(product['variations'])
```

gives all the variations: https://gist.github.com/LucSpan/8185fa540cdd4267744f6c49f4b2a698

---

**Problem**

I can't seem to call or edit product variations.

Following the [explanation in the REST API documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-product-variation), when I try to edit `51369`'s first product variation
with id `52548`, i.e.

`product_variation_1 = uk_wcapi.get('products/51369/variations/52548').json()`

the `product_variation_1` equals,

`{'code': 'rest_no_route',
 'data': {'status': 404},
 'message': 'No route was found matching the URL and request method'}`

I get the above error for any product variation of any of the products with variations.

What am I doing wrong?